# PHP: Arrays displayed as string

Tags: php

I'm trying to parse xml result with php (DOM) :

```
stdClass Object
  (
 [GetBilletResult] => Array
  (
 [0] => stdClass Object
    (
        [tabGrilleHoraire] => stdClass Object
            (
                [tabDetailTarifArticle] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [sNomArticle] => ARTICLE1
                        [tabDetail] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => stdClass Object
                                    (
                                        [sDetail] => Liste Pax [Âge:19]
                                        [sAgePax] => 19;
                                        ...
                                    )

                                [1] => stdClass Object
                                    (
                                        [sDetail] => Prix de Base
                                        [sAgePax] => 18;
                                        ...
                                    )
```

**My code so far:**

```
$processed = array();
foreach( $billets as $GetBilletResult )
    {
        $sNomProduit = $GetBilletResult->getElementsByTagName( "sNomProduit" )->item(0)->nodeValue;
        $sNomArticle = $GetBilletResult->getElementsByTagName( "sNomArticle" )->item(0)->nodeValue;
        $tabDetail = $GetBilletResult->getElementsByTagName( "tabDetail" );

        if (!isset($processed[$sNomProduit])) {
            $processed[$sNomProduit] = array();
        }
        $processed[$sNomProduit][] = array(
                                           'sNomArticle' => $sNomArticle,
                                           'tabDetail' => $tabDetail,
                                           );
    }
```

**The loop to display the results (articles are regrouped by product):**

```
foreach ($processed as $sNomProduit => $list) {
    echo "<h3> ".$sNomProduit."</h3>";
    foreach ($list as $item) {
        echo "<h5> ".$item['sNomArticle'] . "</h5>";
        foreach ($item['tabDetail'] as $node) {
            var_dump ($node->nodeValue);
        }
    }
}
```

**Output (The arrays under "tabDetail" array are displayed as strings)**

> PRODUIT A
>
> ARTICLE A1
>
> string 'Liste Pax : Pax n°1 [Âge:19]19;ADULTE(12-59.99)00000' (length=54)
>
> string 'Prix de Base240300000' (length=21)
>
> ...

Comment: And the question is...?

Comment: You're using `var_dump`, is that intentional? Don't you just want `echo`?

Comment: The arrays under "tabDetail" array should be displayed as arrays not strings

Comment: @Don't Panic. This is not the problem. I'm using `var_dump` to check the result type. Replace it by `echo` doesn't fix the problem.

Comment: This is my [actual sample code](http://img4.hostingpics.net/pics/458888639754screenshot201608104.png) and [tabDetail array structure](http://img4.hostingpics.net/pics/547375screenshot201608103.png).

Comment: From where did you get the dump you have in first snippet?

Comment: A SOAP XML response of a webservice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this part of your code:

```
foreach ($item['tabDetail'] as $node) {
    var_dump ($node->nodeValue);
}
```

If there are more child nodes under `tabDetail`, using `$node->nodeValue` will just get the `textContent` of the node and its descendants. If you want to print the items separately, you should be able to iterate over the `childNodes` and output their values.

```
foreach ($item['tabDetail'] as $node) {
    foreach ($node->childNodes as $child) {
        echo $child->nodeValue;
    }
}
```

Or get the value of specific nodes you want as you are doing in your earlier code:

```
foreach ($item['tabDetail'] as $node) {
    echo $node->getElementsByTagName( "sDetail" )->item(0)->nodeValue;
}
```

Comment: @dont-panic. The tabDetail array : [link](http://img4.hostingpics.net/pics/547375screenshot201608103.png). How can i save it like that, as array of arrays ?

Comment: You mean, instead of outputting the text, you want to save it to a variable?

Comment: Exactly, and keep the original structure.

Comment: I replaced `echo $child->nodeValue;` by `$array1 = $child->nodeValue; array_push($arrayAll, $array1);`. I can't add `$child->nodeValue` as keys

Comment: I would suggest `$arrayAll[$child->nodeName] = $nodeValue;` if you want to get the keys as well as the values. I think that should work.

Comment: It doesn't work properly. I tried [this](http://img4.hostingpics.net/pics/495017screenshot20160818.png) but i need to save all arrays in tabDetail array in one variable (and transfer it then in url using urlencode/urldecode and serialize/unserialize).

Comment: Oh, I guess the way I suggested overwrites for subsequent nodes in `tabDetail`. You could try casting to the nodes to arrays and appending those: `$arrayAll[] = (array) $node;` based on the `var_dump` you showed, I think that could work.

Comment: Euh... i can't find out how to change the code. This is the [big foreach.](http://ideone.com/uFaomm)

Comment: Little help here ? ^^